# Configuring SMTP through Cloudflare

Tags: domain-name-system, cloudflare, smtp

My domain registrar is Cloudflare and my site is hosted through A2 Hosting. My problem is that my email worked fine when A2 Hosting was my domain registrar and web host. Now, neither Thunderbird or Outlook can connect to my server.

My current DNS records for email are:

```
CNAME    mail         my.domain    Auto         Proxied
MX       my.domain    my.domain    120     0    DNS only
```

When attempting to set up my email in Thunderbird I get the following message after entering my email and password:

> Configuration found for a Microsoft Exchange server
>
> Incoming:    IMAP  mail.my.domain  SSL
> Outgoing:    SMTP  mail.my.domain  SSL
> Username:    user@my.domain

When I click on Done, it sits there spinning on **Checking password...** and then says **Unable to log in at server. Probably wrong configuration, username or password.**

When I check my domain at [hardenize.com](https://www.hardenize.com/?host=my.domain) and click on Mail servers on the left side under **Email** it shows **Test failed** under TLS. It also shows that the mail server is operational, STARTTLS is configured as well as DNSSEC. Upon clicking on TLS on the left side it displays this network error for the analysis of the problem:

> A network error occurred while we were trying to communicate with a server.
> **Hostname:** dc-2236d9e77805.my.domain
> **Error message:**
> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
> **IP address:**
> 44.164.145.200

Furthermore, it shows that Email Certificates are not implemented or disabled. I do indeed have a certificate installed and verified through my cPanel.

I tried another tool, [checktls.com](https://www.checktls.com/TestReceiver) and the results display the following message for my certificate:

```
Cert Hostname DOES NOT VERIFY (dc-2236d9e77805.my.domain != *.supercp.com | DNS:*.supercp.com | DNS:supercp.com)
(see RFC-2818 section 3.1 paragraph 4 for info on wildcard ("*") matching)
So email is encrypted but the host is not verified
```

I am at a loss and have been trying to fix this for the past 3 days to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I am now receiving and sending mail. I made the following changes to my DNS records:

> 1. Removed the CNAME record.
> 2. Changed the MX record to:
>    `MX    my.domain    mail.my.domain    120    0    DNS only`
> 3. Copied the URL from the PTR record.
> 4. Found the IP of the URL.
> 5. Created an A record with the IP of that URL:
>    `A     mail    44.164.145.200    Auto    DNS only`

hardenize.com is still showing a java.net.SocketTimeoutException but I believe that is on their end as checktls.com shows everything as good.

Comment: Where exactly is your mail hosted?

Comment: What is the server IP? Or, if you don't want to share it, can you please check using a couple of online services that DNS resolves IP4 and IP6 to your server rather than to a CloudFlare IP.

Comment: My mail is hosted with a2hosting.com. That being said, I think I've just solved my problem using the PTR record. I'll update my question to reflect what I did to solve it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few things that don't make sense. First:

```
CNAME    mail                  prismapixel.studio    Auto         Proxied
```

This means that `mail.prismapixel.studio` is a `CNAME` to `prismapixel.studio.` However, `prismapixel.studio` returns three `A` records, all hosted at Cloudflare. You've stated that Cloudflare does not host your email (naturally, since they're not a mail host). You mention:

> My mail is hosted with a2hosting.com.

If you want to use the hostname `mail.prismapixel.studio` as a means of accessing your mail, you need to point that DNS record to whatever server at a2hosting is hosting your mail.

Furthermore, your `MX` record is pointing to `prismapixel.studio`. However, as we now already know, `prismapixel.studio` returns three `A` records, all hosted at Cloudflare.

Thus you must find the hostname of the mail server that you've been assigned at a2hosting.com for *receiving* email (it could be the same as the server that you use to retrieve mail), and then make that hostname the answer for your `prismapixel.studio`'s `MX` record.

These two things are the causes of the problems you're seeing with your mail client (as well as receiving mail).

Answer (score 1):

To create a service for SMTP, IMAP or POP, if you are using ssl,
you must add SRV @ _smtps _tcp automatic  automatic 0 0 587 mail.prismapixel.studio
and SRV @ _imaps _tcp automatic automatic 0 0 993 mail.prismapixel.studio
or SRV _pop3s _tcp automatic automatic 0 0  995 mail.prismapixel.studio
These 2 services are from cloudflare could  redirect the TCP packets to right port.

Comment: verified the ssl and tls if you are ussing let's encript

Answer (score 0):

To route emails to your mail server you need to have two specific DNS records.

1. An `A` (IPv4) or `AAAA` (IPv6) record for your mail subdomain that points to the IP address of your mail server.

| Type | Name | IPv4 address | Proxy Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | mail | 44.164.145.200 | DNS only |

2. An `MX` record that points to the `A` record subdomain you just created.

| Type | Name | Mail Server | TTL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MX | @ | mail.prismapixel.studio | DNS only |

[Cloudflare documentation](https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/manage-dns-records/how-to/email-records/)